# Is there a better way to link libraries in CMake?

Tags: c++

**strong text**I tried linking nvinfer and Nvonnxparser libraries in CMake like this
link_libraries(nvinfer nvonnxparser ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})

But got the error
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'nvinfer.lib'

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you put the `link_libraries` BEFORE your `add_executable` or `add_library`? Placing it after the add-s causes the build to fail.

Also, prefer using `target_link_libraries` than `link_libraries`, as the [doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_libraries.html) describes:

> The target_link_libraries() command should be preferred whenever possible. Library dependencies are chained automatically, so directory-wide specification of link libraries is rarely needed.

Use it like this, AFTER your `add_executable` or `add_library`:

```
target_link_libraries(TARGET [ITEMS...])
```

where TARGET is one of your just-added targets and ITEMS are libraries to link, by CMake lib names, full paths or generator expressions (like your `${CUDA_LIBRARIES}`).

Comment: You're welcome; please mark the answer as "accepted" if it solves your problem, thanks :)